# I want to show Progress Bar while Sending the image

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I want to send the image through socket and while the sending process going on the progress bar must be displayed and it should be updating when the image is being sending but when i tried this code the progressbar is not been displayed and the image is being send.
I tried this but the progress bar shows directly 100 and the process is still going on and the progress bar shows 100%

```
            int count;         
            try {
            //image send
            client = new Socket(ServerIP,4444);

            File file = new File(path);
            byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            //bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
            OutputStream os = client.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);     
            dos.writeUTF(file.getName()); 
            long total = 0;

            while ((count = bis.read(mybytearray)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/file.length()));
                 os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
                 //os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

            }
           // os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
           // os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
            os.flush();
            bis.close();
            fis.close();
            client.close();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, pleasse show the rest of your code, especially the `publishProgress` method. But most likely you have simply forgotten to call `setMax(...)` and as you receive the first 100 byte it is already at 100%.

Comment: Sorry but this is the actual code for sending image and 1 thing I forgot is int count; above the try{ statement but if you want i'll place the rest of the code which contains the pre, post method and the progressbar details...

Comment: and according to you what should be the max value as I want to see the progress bar progressing from 0  to 100 % when the image is being sended

Comment: actually your implementation of the publishProgress function would be useful, to see how you actually update the ProgressBar